# Filtering timestamps that happened within 5 minutes of each other.

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find glucose results for samples that were done within the last five minutes and filter them out. Below is my PostgreSQL Code and it's output.

```
SELECT date
       , blood_glucose
       , extract(epoch from date - lag(date) OVER(ORDER BY date))/60 
FROM glucose
ORDER BY DATE


date               |glucose|minutes since last    
----------------------------------------------
2017-10-02 08:05:00|183    |681
2017-10-04 08:19:00|275    |2894
2017-10-05 08:03:00|273    |1424
2017-10-05 08:03:00|294    |0
2017-10-05 08:04:00|277    |1
2017-10-05 18:19:00|187    |615
2017-10-09 21:26:00|190    |5947
```

I'm trying to get a result as such:

```
date               |glucose|minutes since last    
----------------------------------------------
2017-10-05 08:03:00|273    |1424
2017-10-05 08:03:00|294    |0
2017-10-05 08:04:00|277    |1
```

I want to get all tests that happened within 5 mins. Not sure how I can contain the first one in this case the very first row with glucose level 273.

Comment: Yes, upto 5mins.

Comment: . . I stated that wrong.  What if the times were 8:03:00, 8:04:00, 8:05:00 and 8:09:00.  Would that last be in the series?  It is six minutes after the first.

Comment: 8:09:00 should be included since the test before it (8:05:00) was only 4 mins. I would normally use scripting language do do this with my query but I was wondering if I could use SQL it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this below sql produces three rows which i think is what you want. It returns any record that had a previous record occurring within 5 minutes, or the next record occurring within 5 minutes.  This is for sqlserver so may not be like for like with postgresql

2017-10-05 08:03:00 294 -1424   0

2017-10-05 08:03:00 273 0   1

2017-10-05 08:04:00 277 -1  615

```
with dat as
(
select '2017-10-02 08:05:00' t,183 g union all
select '2017-10-04 08:19:00',275 union all
select '2017-10-05 08:03:00',273 union all
select '2017-10-05 08:03:00',294 union all
select '2017-10-05 08:04:00',277 union all
select '2017-10-05 18:19:00',187 union all
select '2017-10-09 21:26:00',190
)
select * from
(
    select dat.t,
           g,
           datediff(mi,t,lag (t,1) over (order by t)) timeprev,
           datediff(mi,t,lead (t,1) over (order by t)) timenext
    from   dat
) x
where timeprev >=-5 or timenext <=5
```

Answer (score -1):

You seem to want sequences with more than one element where the difference is less than 5 between any two adjacent elements.

You can do this using `lag()` to identify where the sequences start, then a cumulative sum to identify the sequences, and finally window functions for the length of the sequence.

```
with g as (
      select g.*,
             extract(epoch from date - lag(date) over (order by date)) / 60 as minutes_since_last
      from glucose g
     ),
     gg as (
      select g.*, sum( (minutes_since_last <= 5)::int) over (order by date) as grp
      from g
     ),
     ggg as (
      select gg.*, count(*) over (partition by grp) as cnt
      from gg
     )
select ggg.*
from ggg
where cnt > 1
order by date;
```